# Aggregate function MAX giving unexpected output when used inside a HAVING clause

Tags: mysql, sql

The Table

| Id | Salary |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 300 |

I want to find out all the salaries lesser the highest salary. For doing so, i have come up with the following query-

```
SELECT salary FROM Employee HAVING salary<max(salary);
```

Which yields the output-

`{"headers": ["salary"], "values": [[100]]}`

But my expected output here is

`{"headers": ["salary"], "values": [[100], [200]]}`

If i used the constant value 300 instead of max(salary) i can obtain my expected value.

I'm unable to understand why using the aggregate function MAX in HAVING is resulting in the wrong output here. Also, i do not want to accomplish this using WHERE because i'm trying to use this query as a sub-query for a larger question i'm trying to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL then you can use window function.

```
select salary from 
( select salary,rank()over(order by salary desc) rnk from employee) t
where rnk>1
```

Or you can use subquery:

```
Select salary
FROM Employee
WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM Employee)
```

Answer (score 1):

Logically, this query should produce an error:

```
SELECT salary
FROM Employee
HAVING salary < max(salary);
```

[And it does in the more recent versions of MySQL.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1b32927c0f68b5a67b3e1d0ffc79bbe6)

You want a subquery.  And `HAVING` is not necessary:

```
SELECT salary
FROM Employee
WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(e2.salary) FROM Employee e2)
```